# On the construction of a certain sequence of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be a fixed (positive) number. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we choose $\varepsilon_k >0$ with the property that $\lim_k \varepsilon_k =0$.

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, we know that there exist infinitely many $q_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon_k \leq \{q_k \alpha \} \leq \frac{1}{2},
$$
since $\{q \alpha\}$ is dense in $[0,1)$. Here $\{ z \}$ denotes the fractional part of a number $z$, i.e. $\{z\} = z -[z]$. Can we also choose $q_k$ such that $q_k = O(\varepsilon_k^{-1})$? In other words, can we select $q_k$ so that $\limsup_k \varepsilon_k q_k < \infty$?

It seems to me that the answer is not trivial, since we are, roughly speaking, trying to single out a *slow* sequence of approximation. Maybe this holds only for some particular (kind of) irrational number $\alpha$.

**Edit.** It seems that there is a positive result if one requires the weaker condition $k/\varepsilon_k \geq q_k$, see [here](http://www.math.klte.hu/publi/load_jpg.php?p=1949). Of course $q_k$ can be much larger than we need.

Comment: What does $\lim_k$ mean?

Comment: @joro $\lim_k = \lim_{k \to +\infty}$, the only possible limit as $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think this should be true using some form of the pigeonhole principle, like Dirichlet's approximation theorem.

Comment: @benblumsmith Do you think it is so easy? Take for instance $\varepsilon_k = 2^{-k}$. Then we want $q_k \lesssim 2^k$. I don't see how a pigeonhole principle can be invoked. How can we bound, *a priori*, the largeness of the integer $q_k$? In some sense there are too few integers below $2^k$...

Answer (score 3):

For each positive integer $N$, let $A_N$ be the set of $\alpha$ such that for every positive integer $k$ there is a positive integer $q_k$ with $q < N \epsilon_k^{-1}$ and 
$1/2 - \epsilon_k \le \{q_k \alpha\} \le 1/2$.

Note that if $\alpha = b/c$ is rational with $c$ odd, $1/2 - \epsilon_k \le \{q_k \alpha\} \le 1/2$ is impossible unless $2 c \epsilon_k \ge 1$.  So $A_N$ is a closed set that contains no rationals with odd denominator, and thus is nowhere dense.  By the Baire category theorem, the union of these is a meagre set.  In particular, there exist irrationals not in that union.  For such $\alpha$, you can't have $q_k = O(\epsilon_k^{-1})$.

Comment: It is very interesting. I suspected that this could be true only for most irrationals. However I am unable to make a reasonable guess.

Comment: Another thing I suspect is that the constant $C$ in the upper bound $q_k \leq C \varepsilon_k^{-1}$ has a role. There seem to be (partial) results with a small $C$.